# Pattern to select all non-directory files recursivly

Tags: linux

I am need to remove **x** permission recursively (chmod -R...) from all files inside a directory, but all sub directorates should retain **x** permission.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
find /your/directory -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod -x
```

`-type f` will only list files, not directories. The `-print0` and `-0` are to make things work if you have strange filenames (e.g. with spaces in them).